# Updating UILabel from connectionDidReceiveData is not working

Tags: objective-c, connection, uilabel

In my connection DidReceiveData method I have an NSLog that prints the percentage data received and it is working well. I need to display this percentage on a UILabel but the UILabel is not getting updated. I am able to update the UILabel from other methods like viewDidLoad or by pressing a button. But from the connection did receive data I am not getting any change. What could be the catch here. There is nothing wrong with my Label, and my calculations. Does this method get run in the background or something.

Comment: What happens when you just change the value of the UILabel in didRecieveData? Set the UILabel text to something like @"Did receive data" so you can tell if it is actually being updated.

Comment: @Carter that does not work from there also. I tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you haven't done anything funky to make that run on a background queue/thread (it should be main queue/thread by default), there are a couple possibilities that come to mind:

1. The method is getting called before your view is actually set up.  This could certainly happen in certain circumstances where you kick off network activity before you set up the UI.
2. The actual `UILabel` isn't wired up correctly, though this seems unlikely if things work in `-viewDidLoad`.

To test, break in the method and `po myLabel` to make sure it's not nil.

Comment: no my code is pretty simple, no fancy threading or anything, And yes I have placed a break point and the UILabel is not nil.. I have been googling and a number of people have faced this problem, can't find a solution though..

Comment: Huh.  Just out of curiosity, what happens if you explicitly send the label `-setNeedsDisplay` (though you shouldn't have to)?

Comment: tried that long back and didn't work. Thanks though.  Just after updating the UILabel i have written an NSLog(@"value there:%@", myUILabel.text)  and it actually prints the value that should be on the label. The UILabel itself however, remains as "0" (not updating)

Comment: OK, having exhausted the obvious things, let's try something a little more exotic: break on `[UILabel setText]`.  I'm wondering whether KVO (or something similar) is canceling out your change, which would be reflected by multiple `-setText:` calls.

Comment: if that where the case, wouldn't the last setText actually show. My UILabel is not even showing the last setText:value

Comment: I meant that something really unexpected might be setting it to the old value.  I'm grasping at straws, but as the saying goes, "once you've eliminated the impossible, whatever's left, however improbable, must be the truth."  (The breakpoint would be a good test anyway just to verify the target label is actually getting the expected message.)

Comment: thanks for you patience. I don't really know what to do with breakPoints. I know how to set one in Xcode, and ofcoz setting the switch on the toolBar that says "breakpoints" to on. After running the app I am not sure what to do with the information it gives me.. Please help

Comment: I'm going to dinner right now but can come back later; are you using gdb or lldb for debugging?

Comment: just checked my active scheme. Am using lldb

Comment: Try checking the address of the UILabel before and after the DidReceiveData and verify its still the same. Post some code.

Comment: I think you can do it through the breakpoint inspector, but also just try pausing execution and, in the debug console, `breakpoint set -n "-[UILabel setText:]"`

Comment: @Conrad you were right, it was something small and interesting. I simply changed my to code from e.g. myLabel.text="hello"  to  [myLabel setText:@"hello"] and that way works. I thought either way worked, please correct me if Im wrong

Comment: Those *should* be equivalent (assuming you had an @ in your first case to make it an `NSString`), so I can't see how that could affect things.  I almost wonder if your code just needed a clean build.  (FWIW, I never use dot syntax, but it really shouldn't make a difference.)  Glad you got it working!